# How to get the CheckBox selected value in insert into database controller in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Hi all i have to get the selected value from checkbox into my post method into insert into the database controller. How can i do this?

```
My Model Code
-----------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections;

namespace Gridview_BugTracker.Models
{
    public class BugTracker_DataHelper
    {

        public static List<BugTracker_DataHelper> GetList{get;set;}

           public int ProjectId { get; set; }
           public string projectName { get; set; }           
           public string Description { get; set; }
           public  string status { get; set; }
           public int EmployeId { get; set; }
           public string EmployeName { get; set; }
           public bool selectChkbox { get; set; }         
      }      

   }

    My Control code
    ------------------------------

     using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Data;
    using Gridview_BugTracker.Models;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace Gridview_BugTracker.Controllers
    {
        public class ProjectsController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Projects/
            /// <summary>
            ///
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var bugedlist = GetList();
                return View(bugedlist);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// The Bind data in Gridview
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public List<BugTracker_DataHelper> GetList()
            {
                var modelList = new List<BugTracker_DataHelper>();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS"))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Projects", conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(dCmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    conn.Close();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        var model = new BugTracker_DataHelper();
                        model.ProjectId = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjectId"]);
                        model.projectName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["projectName"].ToString();
                        model.Description = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
                        model.status = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
                        modelList.Add(model);
                    }
                }
                return modelList;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Assign The Project Display
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
            public ViewResult AssignProject()
            {

                ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(Assinedwork(), "ProjectId", "projectName");           
                var employees = CheckBoxBindEmpName();
                return View(employees);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Assignwork
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>        
            public List<BugTracker_DataHelper> Assinedwork()
            {
                var modelList = new List<BugTracker_DataHelper>();

                using (SqlConnection assignedconn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS"))
                {
                    {
                        assignedconn.Open();
                        SqlCommand Passnedcmd = new SqlCommand("select ProjectId,projectName from Projects", assignedconn);
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Passnedcmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);

                        for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            var model = new BugTracker_DataHelper();
                            model.ProjectId = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjectId"]);
                            model.projectName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["projectName"].ToString();
                            modelList.Add(model);
                        }
                    }
                    return modelList;
                }
            }

            public List<BugTracker_DataHelper> CheckBoxBindEmpName()
            {
                var modecheckbox = new List<BugTracker_DataHelper>();

                using (SqlConnection assignedconn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS"))
                {
                    {
                        assignedconn.Open();
                        SqlCommand Chkcmd = new SqlCommand("select EmployeId,EmployeeName from EmployeeDetails", assignedconn);
                        SqlDataAdapter Chkda = new SqlDataAdapter(Chkcmd);
                        DataSet chkds = new DataSet();
                        Chkda.Fill(chkds);

                        for (int i = 0; i <= chkds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            var modelchk = new BugTracker_DataHelper();
                            modelchk.EmployeId = Convert.ToInt16(chkds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EmployeId"]);
                            modelchk.EmployeName = chkds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EmployeeName"].ToString();
                            modecheckbox.Add(modelchk);
                        }

                    }
                }
                return modecheckbox;
         }
        }

    }
    My Assinedcode View code
    ------------------------

     <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>>" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>AssignProject</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
         <% using (Html.BeginForm()) 
         { %>      
        <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
         <fieldset>
            <legend>Projects</legend>
                        <%: Html.DropDownList("ProjectId")%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectId")%>                   
                        <fieldset style="color:Blue;">                 

                        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>  
                      <div>
                      <%:Html.CheckBox(item.EmployeName) %>
                      <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.EmployeName) %>
                      </div>                 
                    <%} %>
                          <p>
                          <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
                         </p>      

            </fieldset>
        <%} %>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

now i want to get the selected value EmployeeName  Parameter in my postmedthod in insert into database. Can anyone help me with how i should do this?

Comment: @Gaz ...THank you for spelling correction

Comment: Paste only the portion of the code which is necessary.

Comment: @Mohayemin..when slect the checkbox value the insert into datbase..

Comment: When you wanted to save the data into the DB, when you are checking the checkbox, you can very well grab the click event for the checkbox in jQuery and then post the form to send the data to the controller, there by saving the data.